# Are Android's class loaders different from Oracle's?

Tags: java, android, jvm, classloader

As we know, we typically have three kinds of class loaders in Java : Bootstrap, Extension, System.
But I think this is not the case for Android.

From Google's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni) :

> This usually does what you want. You can get into trouble if you
>   create a thread yourself (perhaps by calling pthread_create and then
>   attaching it with AttachCurrentThread). Now there are no stack frames
>   from your application. If you call FindClass from this thread, the
>   JavaVM will start in the "**system**" class loader instead of the one
>   associated with your **application**, so attempts to find **app-specific**
>   classes will fail.

I bolded some keywords here. As you can see, they mentioned SYSTEM CLASS LOADER and also say that system class loader doesn't load app-specific classes.
This confuses me. With typical JVM, system class loader, which is also called application class loader, loads application's own or third-party classes.
But the description above says something different.

So I ran some simple test code like below:

```
System.out.println(java.util.ArrayList.class.getClassLoader());
System.out.println(com.myapp.MyApp.class.getClassLoader());
```

In eclipse, as you can expect, the first line prints "**null**",

while the second one prints "**sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@xxxxxxxx**".

But when I run this code on my Android 8.0 device,
the former returns "**java.lang.BootClassLoader@xxxxxxx**"

while the latter returns
 '**dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myproject-fws-bX_CTH09QygC3XTUeA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.examp....."**'.

I ran again with below lines inside the `onCreate()` method on the Android device :

```
java.util.ArrayList.class.getClassLoader().getParent();
com.myapp.MyApp.class.getClassLoader().getParent();
com.myapp.MyApp.class.getClassLoader().getParent().getParent();
this.getClass().getClassLoader();  // this is the same as just calling getClassLoader().
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getParent();
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getParent().getParent();
```

This time, the first one returns "**null**",

the second "**java.lang.BootClassLoader@xxxxxxx**",

the third "**null**",

the fourth '**dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myproject-fws-bX_CTH09QygC3XTUeA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.examp....."**',

the fifth "**java.lang.BootClassLoader@xxxxxxx**",

the sixth "**null**" respectively.

I'm not sure what all this exactly means, but it's different anyway.

Does anyone know about Android's class loaders, or could you give me any link related to this?

PS. I also tested loading my app-specific classes with both `PathClassLoader` and `BootClassLoader`, and only `PathClassLoader` could load them successfully.

Comment: Yes they are different. Android has a completely separate implementation of Java.